# Partly initialising C-arrays from different files

Tags: c, arrays

My objective is to instantiate an array in one C-file and have it initialised in different files **only through declarative code**, i.e., if the following would work, that'd be awesome:

```
// File1.c
int myArray[2];

// FileA.c
myArray[0] = 123;

// FileB.c
myArray[1] = 345;
```

The key here is that the code in FileA and FileB is not executed, but what I'd like to see is the compiler picking up these statements to initialise myArray.

What I'm really trying to accomplish here is some form of compilation-based service registration. I.e., in my real code, the array would hold pointers to functions, and my "main" (in File1.c) would not know which specific functions are compiled into the image. Via a different makefile, I would compile different combinations of my files (FileA, FileB, FileC...) and have the functions they implement available to my main via pointers.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this is a 'no fly zone'; it isn't going to work in the raw form.  You have to initialize an array in one place, and only one place.

Comment: Questions for you: how does `FileB.c` know it should use slot 1 and `FileA.c` know it should use slot 0.  Which slot should `FileC.c` use?  What happens if `FileA.c` is not used in one of your combinations?  Is its slot left null, or can it be used by another file?  Does it matter which sequence the array is filled in? How does the build system know which files are to be used?

Comment: Is there a reason to not just have FileA, FileB and FileC provide different definitions for the same function name?  main calls foo.  When linked with FileA.o it get foo() defined in FileA, when linked against FileB.o it gets foo() defined in FileB, etc.

Comment: dohashi - I'm looking for a solution that will enable me to include multiple files in a single linked image, so there can be only one "foo"...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize an array piecemeal across several files.  You're only allowed one initializer in one file.  So, that idea isn't going to work directly.

How can you make it work?  You have pointers to functions; I assume they all have the same signature, which can be `int function(int arg)` for the purposes of this discussion (the details don't matter).  It will be defined in a header, and that header will be needed by `File1.c`.

```
typedef int (*Function)(int arg);
```

Each service provider file will have an associated header, `FileA.c` has a header `FileA.h`, and so on.

The code that initializes the array could be in `File1.c` or in a separate file.  Wherever it is, it will have to be cognizant of which modules (services) are to be linked:

```
#include "configuration.h"
#include "FileA.h"
#include "FileB.h"
#include "FileC.h"

Function services[] =
{
#ifdef INCLUDE_SERVICE_A
     A_service_function,
#endif
#ifdef INCLUDE_SERVICE_B
     B_service_function,
#endif
#ifdef INCLUDE_SERVICE_C
     C_service_function,
#endif
};
size_t num_services = sizeof(services) / sizeof(services[0]);
```

This scheme has the benefit that there is no wasted space in the array.  It also won't compile if none of the three services are requested.  The build system will ensure that `configuration.h` includes the correct defines.  The per-service headers declare the service functions.

So that gives an outline of a workable scheme.

Comment: Thanks for all the data. That corroborated my concerns :-). Jonathan - addressing your first question(s) - the intention was for the makefile system to handle which file goes and and which doesn't, as well as determine the indices for each function. Your suggestion for the function pointers is pretty much what we have right now in the system, and that is what I'm trying to remove - we have multiple users, and I don't want them to all touch the "top" files. Seems like I'll be going for auto-generated code - the make would invoke a script that will create a file with the initialisations.